# Custom ListView issue with onTouch when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a custom `ListView` in which I have set an `OnTouchListener` for each list item. When the user touches the item, I use `TransitionDrawable` to change the background color of the item during `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and bring it back to normal during `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

Now when I scroll this list, the item which is touched at the start of the scroll action changes background color. I want to avoid this behavior. So while scrolling I want to disable any change in background color. Is there a way to do this? Please see the code below:

```
public class ListItemOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Context mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            TransitionDrawable transitionDown = (TransitionDrawable) res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.row_background_transition_down);
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(transitionDown);
            transitionDown.startTransition(350);
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            TransitionDrawable transitionUp = (TransitionDrawable) res
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.row_background_transition_up);
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(transitionUp);
            transitionUp.startTransition(1000);
            // Get list view
            ListView listView = getListView();
            int position = listView.getPositionForView((LinearLayout) v.getParent());
            listView.performItemClick(v, position, 0);
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP");
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_MOVE");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_CANCEL");
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_background_normal);
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's not so important to undo the effect on ACTION_UP then you could replace that with a timer and use click or select events?

Comment: Actually it's important to change the color back while ACTION_UP as I want to show a fading effect. Also I'm generating an itemclick event while ACTION_UP as I want to register user's click. Please see the code that I have in my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

When the user starts scrolling you should get an ACTION_CANCEL.  Catch this and change the color back.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent it from ever changing colors at all?  That's kind of impossible-  you can't know at touch down time whether or not it will be scrolled in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen the android Contacts app which shows your phone's contact list. It does exactly what I'm trying to do. If you scroll the list, it never changes color. When you touch or click the list item, it shows a fading effect and then opens the contact's details screen. Also yahoo mail's android app which shows your email in a listview has the same behavior.

Comment: I must have a different contacts app, I don't get that at all.  I get fading colors even when I scroll.  But think about it logically-  the finger touches the screen.  At that point you change the color.  1 second later, the user scrolls.  Its already changed colors, so its too late to prevent it.  There's no way to have that effect perfectly.  You can post a delayed messsage to a handler that sets the color in response, and delete the message if you see a cancel before its processed-  that would come close to it, but not be a 100% solution.

Comment: Yes I understand your point, but since I have seen this behavior in the contacts app on ICS, there might be some way to do it. Maybe they are passing the onTouch event to the item's parent (i.e. the listview in this case) to handle it, or using a gesture listener. I have tried different things but haven't been able to achieve it. It's not a big deal but it enhances the aesthetics. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing on touch, u can implement onListItemClick(will work same as on touch) and then on that method u can write the code to change the color of the list item touched/clicked.